# What does the $F(dy)$ in $\int_{y<x} g(y)F(dy)$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

What does the $F(dy)$ in
$$f(x)=\int_{y<x}g(y)F(dy)$$
means?

Note that $F$ is a distribution function/probability measure.

Furthermore, how to use Cauchy-Schwarz to get the below:
$$
|f(x)|^2\leq F(x)\int g^2 dF
$$
I came across this from a proof in Huber's "Robust Statistics". The picture contains full details of the proof.

--- Edit ---

If someone could verify Masacroso's answer, it would be great.

---

[image]

Comment: It represent the measure defined by $F$

Comment: When you write it as $dF$ then I agree but $F(dy)$???

Comment: I think that in the second notation he is specifying the variable of integration $y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments this is just a notation to specify the variable of integration, that is, notations like $dF, dF(y), F(dy)$ are exactly the same thing. Indeed it can be seen because in the cited text it says that $f$ is the density of $F$ and $g=f'/f$, and this agree with $F(dy)=f(y) dy$ as

$$
\int_{y<x}g(y)F(dy)=\int_{y<x}\frac{f'(y)}{f(y)}f(y)dy=\int_{y<x}f'(y)dy=f(x)
$$

Comment: This makes sense. If someone else could verify this in a comment/answer then I would be minded to accept.

Comment: I see now this is a common notation in stochastic process. Sometimes people write $F(\mathbb{R})$ denote a measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @chuck the notation is not uncommon, check [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24F(dx)%24&p=1), sometimes you can find also notations like $P(dx)$ where $P$ is a probability measure