# An application of Integration by part

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you get the equality below using by parts?
$$
\Big(\int \psi' f dx \Big)^2=\Big(\int \psi \frac{f'}{f}f dx\Big)^2
$$
where $f$ and $\psi$ are continuously differentiable functions with compact support.

Using by part one time yields
$$
\psi f -\int \psi f' dx
$$
which does resemble the equality above somewhat except the $\psi f$.

--- Edit ---

Detail setting can be seen in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082380/what-does-the-fdy-in-int-yx-gyfdy-mean). The above equality is stated on the first line of the proof.

Comment: Is there a domain of integration given in the problem?

Comment: Presumably you want to integrate over a superset of all the supports so the boundary term drops out.

Comment: I have linked another question which provides full detail of the setting. I am just concerned with one line of the proof.

Comment: @Ian if $f$ is a symmetric density, would that give the desired result?

Comment: @chuck If the domain of integration is $\mathbb{R}$, can you see the equality?

Comment: @Gary I would say no because it could go to infinity

Comment: What about the compact supports of $f$ and $\psi$? What does it tell you about $
\left[ {\psi f} \right]_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } $?

Comment: Got it. Compact support means they are zero in the limit. Thanks!!

Comment: @Gary If you write a short and self-contained anwser below I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the integration is over $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\psi$ and $f$ are of compact support, they vanish at infinity. Thus,
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi '(x)f(x)dx}  = \left[ {\psi '(x)f(x)} \right]_{x =  - \infty }^{x =  + \infty }  - \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi (x)f'(x)dx}  =  - \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi (x)f'(x)dx} .
$$
Squaring both sides yields the claim.